# Qt OSX fullscreen window upper menuBar and Dock

Tags: c++, macos, qt

Qt5.6, OS X El Capitan. I have a problem, I need to select an area on the screen to take a screenshot, but the menu bar and dock are always on my window.

My code:

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QRect desktop = screen->virtualGeometry();

region = new SelectRegion;

region->setGeometry(desktop);
region->show();
region->focusWidget();
region->activateWindow();
region->raise();
```

Region Window has flags: Qt::Window, Qt::FramelessWindowHint, Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint.

How to move my window to the top?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Qt::WindowFlags windowFlags =
        Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint |
        Qt::BypassWindowManagerHint |
        Qt::FramelessWindowHint |
        Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint |
        Qt::ToolTip;

setWindowFlags(windowFlags);
```

should do it...

Answer (score 0):

The flag Qt::Popup together with setting it's size to the screen's size should do the trick, however notice, that it will likely break keyboard focus.